# Compilation error in writing a client side program

Tags: c, sockets

I am ***new*** to socket programming.I looked at a program in the Tutorialspoint.I made a little changes to the program but while compiling I am encountering errors.I am attaching an image telling about the errors.[image].

In addition, I don't understand what is sin_family and sin_port.Shall I replace them with serv_addr_family and serv_addr_port respectively?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define portno 5432

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd,n;
const struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
const struct hostent *server;

char buffer[256];

if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    return;
}

server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    return;
}

/* Create a socket point */
bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy(*server->h_addr, 
       (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr,
            server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
{
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    return;
}    
/* Now connect to the server */
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
{
     perror("ERROR connecting");
     return;
}   
/* Now ask for a message from the user, this message
* will be read by server
*/
printf("Please enter the message: ");
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
/* Send message to the server */
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
{
     perror("ERROR writing to socket");
     return;
}
/* Now read server response */
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) 
{
     perror("ERROR reading from socket");
     return;
}
printf("%s\n",buffer);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't use bzero and bcopy, they are very old and should be replaced with memset and memcopy (or memmove).

Comment: Please have a `return` value in your error-checking statements. Leads to  `-Wreturn-type`. Its better coding practice.

Comment: Mmm, I like how your terminal is transparent and I can mainly see what's under it. Do not post screenshots in question, when you can just copy output as text...

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove const before the stuct.
it's used to configure your socket.(port, ip, ...)

```
int sockfd,n;
const struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
const struct hostent *server;
```

to

```
int sockfd,n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to correct here:

1. Firstly,

   ```
   const struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   ```

   You won't be able to modify `serv_addr` as it is **read-only**.
   So you may need to remove the `const` keyword.
2. On rectifying the above step. You will still run into undefined-behavior in the following statement.

   ```
    bcopy(*server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr, server->h_length);
   ```

   Change to to below:

   ```
    bcopy(server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr, server->h_length);
   ```

   Notice the removal of `*` in the first argument.
    The deference is incorrect.
    As per comments, I too recommend usage of `memcpy` like functions.
3. As a part of good coding practice. Always return with the proper return-type.
   Leads to `-Wreturn-type` as your `main` expects an `int` returned .

   ```
    Example Change: 
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        return;
    }
   ```

   to `return -1` *maybe*.

Comment: Using bzero and bcopy is bad, you should show OP to use memcpy and memset

Comment: @zoska, If I show him everything, what's the OP gonna do on his own ? Indicating to use memcpy over bcopy isnt enough. That's why you would vote down this ?

Comment: It's not clear what's so bad about bzero and bcopy anyway; they are old-fashioned but they do work and they aren't going anywhere.

Comment: The fact they've been removed from the POSIX specification is an obvious drawback.